# how to install sigar api to java maven corretto program

Tags: java, api, sigar

help please. how to install sigar api to java maven corretto program. i need it but i dont know how to install it. any tutorials on internet didnt work / they didnt showed how to do it.
it sometimes worked but after compiling it showed error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=3876, tid=0x0000000000002584
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_292-b10) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.292-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\mjacz\OneDrive\Pulpit\SysInfo32\SysInfo32\hs_err_pid3876.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You should probably try using OpenJDK 11 unless you have a specific need for Corretto 8

Comment: but i probably need corretto 8